# guardar los meses comprendidos entre dos fechas en una tabla

Tags: java

mi pregunta es como puedo guardar (obtener) los meses comprendido entre dos fechas, adjunto la imagen de como mas o menos debería quedar

[image: en la imagen se puede ver, que dado dos fechas lo que se quiere es que se guarde los meses y el año en la tabla al pulsar el botón pagos mensuales]

Comment: Para poder ayudarte, por favor muéstranos el código que tienes hasta el momento.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo en tu preguntar quieres saber la diferencia entre los meses, deberías formular mejor la pregunta si no es así.
Por la imagen que veo estas usando el jDateChooser así que aunque lo puedes hacer usando Date me parece más rápido así.

```
 //Creas dos instancia de objeto Calendar
    Calendar fecha1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar fecha2= Calendar.getInstance();
    //Les pasas a esas instancias las fechas en tu jDateChooser
    fecha1.setTime(jDateChooser1.getDate());
    fecha2.setTime(jDateChooser2.getDate());
    // Calculas la diferencia entre ambas fechas, osea el tiempo comprendido entre una y otra.
    // El math.abs para el valor absoluto así no importa el orden de que fecha entra primero
    int diferencia = Math.abs(fecha2.get(Calendar.MONTH) - fecha1.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    //Imprime el resultado o en tu caso guardalo en un array o no sé lo que harás.
    System.out.println(diferencia);
```